# NoneType' object has no attribute in python?

Tags: python

I already did this part of code but it show me this error when I ran it

```
for tmp in links:
    jobref=re.search('jobId=(\d+)&', tmp).group()+".html"
    print(jobref)
    if tmp not in os.listdir('.'):
        file=open(jobref,"w+")
        file.write(urllib.urlopen(tmp).read())
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Any Idea on how to fix it?

Comment: The `re.search` is probably returning `None`

Answer (score 0):

You have no required substring in string `tmp`, consequently `re.search` returns `None`. `None` has ho attribute `group()`. You have to check `re.search` returned type before `group()` method calling.

```
result = re.search('jobId=(\d+)&', tmp)
if result:
    jobref = result.group() + ".html"
else:
    ...
```